# Select from array next upcoming date

Tags: php, arrays, date

Okay essentially what I'm trying to achieve is grab the next upcoming date from the array. Below I have posted my array and how I select the current date.

```
$payout_dates = array('16-04-14','16-04-28','16-05-14');
$currentdate = date('y-m-d');
```

What I'm trying to do is select the next upcoming date from the array using the `current date` so for example today is `16-04-27` so the next upcoming date would be `16-04-28` Below I'm going to paste the code im using to select the next upcoming date however the only problem with changing the code below is that it is used for a `select` so having troubles just using it to echo out the date itself.

```
<?php
   foreach ($payout_dates as $i => $d) {
    if ($currentdate >= $d && ($i == count($date)-1 || $currentdate < $date[$i+1])) {
        $selected = "selected";
        $selected_int = $i;
    } else {
        $selected = "";
    }
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $d);
    echo "<option $selected>" . date("m/d/Y", strtotime($d)) . "</option>";
 }
?>
```

Just to reliterate the problem I'm having is selecting the next upcoming date from the current date.

Comment: Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert dates to integers (timestamps). It will be easier to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$payout_dates = array('16-04-14','16-04-28','16-05-14');
$currentdate = date('y-m-d');
```

If you don't want to convert dates using `strtotime()` the following might be used to select the date using string comparison since you have a lexicographical order on the dates.

```
$found = false;
foreach ($payout_dates as $i => $d) {
    if (! $found && strcmp($currentdate, $d) < 0) {
        $found = true;
        $selected = ' selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $selected = "";
    }
}
echo "<option $selected>" . date("m/d/Y", strtotime($d)) . "</option>";
```

Otherwise, you would go with the following solution:

```
$payout_times = array_map('strtotime', $payout_dates);
$currenttime = strtotime(date('y-m-d'));

$found = false;
foreach ($payout_times as $i => $d) {
    if (! $found && strcmp($currenttime, $d) < 0) {
        $found = true;
        $selected = ' selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $selected = "";
    }
}
echo "<option $selected>" . date("m/d/Y", $d) . "</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your dates to PHP DateTime objects, you can call sort() on the array. Something like this - note I've deliberately changed the last array element to be the earliest chronological date to prove the sorting works:

```
<?php 
$payout_dates = array(new DateTime('16-04-14'), new DateTime('16-04-28'), new DateTime('16-03-14'));
sort($payout_dates);

foreach($payout_dates as $i => $date) {
     [...]
}
```