# How to get closest birthday date from array + print name in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Started to use PHP about 2 weeks ago,got first problems =D

Can't figure how to get my task done.

Program have to give next upcoming birthday and name.Thanks in advance

How to make this programm print out something like :

Jessy Pinkmann  2017-09-11

```
<?php

$today=new DateTime();


$Bdays = array
(
    array("Lucienne Adkisson",date_create("2017-10-17")),            //0    //  Y/M/D
    array("Sheryll Nestle",date_create("2017-02-16")),            //1
    array("Tim Pittman",date_create("2017-07-29")),           //2
    array("Elmer Letts",date_create("2017-12-01")),                 //3
    array("Gino Massengale",date_create("2017-04-16")),              //4
    array("Jeremy Wiggs ",date_create("2017-09-17")),            //5
    array("Julian Bulloch ",date_create("2017-06 -21")),             //6
    array("Joella Hinshaw  ",date_create("2017-06-25")),                //7
    array("Mamie Burchill  ",date_create("2017-11-15")),                    //8
    array("Constance Segers  ",date_create("2017-06-30")),                //9
    array("Jessy Pinkmann",date_create("2017-09-11")),             //10
    array("Dudley Currie",date_create("2017-02-10"))             //11
);


for ($x =0; $x <= 11; $x++ ){


$diff=date_diff($today,$Bdays[$x][1]);
echo $diff->format("  %R%a");

}

?>
```

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Make some research. Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901555/select-from-array-next-upcoming-date

Comment: Thanks!I can find next upcoming date,but i just cant figure how to add name to it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```html
<?php
$today=new DateTime();
$count = 0;


$Bdays = array(
    array("Lucienne Adkisson",date_create("2017-10-17")),            
    array("Sheryll Nestle",date_create("2017-02-16")),            
    array("Tim Pittman",date_create("2017-07-29")),           
    array("Elmer Letts",date_create("2017-12-01")),                 
    array("Gino Massengale",date_create("2017-04-16")),              
    array("Jeremy Wiggs ",date_create("2017-09-17")),            
    array("Julian Bulloch ",date_create("2017-06 -21")),             
    array("Joella Hinshaw  ",date_create("2017-06-25")),               
    array("Mamie Burchill  ",date_create("2017-11-15")),                   
    array("Constance Segers  ",date_create("2017-06-30")),                
    array("Jessy Pinkmann",date_create("2017-09-11")),             
    array("Dudley Currie",date_create("2017-02-10"))             
);



for($x = 0, $len = count($Bdays); $x < $len; $x++){

    $diff = date_diff($today, $Bdays[$x][1]);
   
    $difference = $diff->format("  %R%a");
    if($difference > 0){
        if($count == 0){
            $smallest_diff = $difference;
        }
        $count++;
        if($difference < $smallest_diff){
            $smallest_diff = $difference;
            $closest_index = $x;
        }
    }
}

echo "The upcoming birtday person is: <b>" . $Bdays[$closest_index][0] . '</b> and his birthday is on: <b>' . date_format($Bdays[$closest_index][1], "Y/m/d") . '</b>';

?>
```

It's woking fine. Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!Gonna give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

I have restructured some of your code.

```
<?php
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$Bdays = array
(
    array("Lucienne Adkisson", "2017-10-17"),
    array("Sheryll Nestle", "2017-02-16"),
    array("Tim Pittman", "2017-07-29"),
    array("Elmer Letts", "2017-12-01"),
    array("Gino Massengale", "2017-04-16"),
    array("Jeremy Wiggs", "2017-09-17"),
    array("Julian Bulloch", "2017-06 -21"),
    array("Joella Hinshaw", "2017-06-25"),
    array("Mamie Burchill", "2017-11-15"),
    array("Constance Segers", "2017-06-30"),
    array("Jessy Pinkmann", "2017-09-11"),
    array("Dudley Currie", "2017-02-10")
);


$tmp = 366;
$closest = ["", 0];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Bdays); $i++)
{
    if (abs(strtotime($today) - strtotime($Bdays[$i][1])) / 86400 < $tmp)
    {
        $tmp = abs(strtotime($today) - strtotime($Bdays[$i][1])) / 86400;
        $closest = [$Bdays[$i][0], $Bdays[$i][1]];
    }
}
?>
```

`$tmp` is set to have no value and be 366 days. This is the variable that will store the closest date to today's date. I have also changed the for loop to use the [`count` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) which means that if you add more dates to `$Bdays` then it will iterate more times for the for loop.

`$closest` stores the name and birthday of the closest date to the today.

The [`abs` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) will convert negative numbers to positive numbers. This is because if you had a difference of `-138` for instance, that would be less than `38` even though that would mean the date was `100` days further away, just simply because negative numbers are lower.

#### Update

I have updated the code. This new code will now work regardless of the year. I changed it because obviously, birthdays don't count the year. This will be useful if someone's birthday was something like "2015-04-10" will count as the closest as that is only 1 day away, even though it is 2 years and 1 day away.

I have written a comment in the code. What this means is that if you want to take the years into account then set `$format = "Y-m-d"` but if you don't want to take years into account then set `$format = "m-d"` and this will just subtract the difference between months and the days.

```
<?php
$format = "Y-m-d"; // change to "m-d" to ignore years
$today = date($format);

$Bdays = array
(
    array("Lucienne Adkisson", strtotime("2017-10-17")),
    array("Sheryll Nestle", strtotime("2017-02-16")),
    array("Tim Pittman", strtotime("2017-07-29")),
    array("Elmer Letts", strtotime("2017-12-01")),
    array("Gino Massengale", strtotime("2016-04-16")),
    array("Jeremy Wiggs", strtotime("2017-09-17")),
    array("Julian Bulloch", strtotime("2017-06 -21")),
    array("Joella Hinshaw", strtotime("2017-06-25")),
    array("Mamie Burchill", strtotime("2017-11-15")),
    array("Constance Segers", strtotime("2017-06-30")),
    array("Jessy Pinkmann", strtotime("2017-09-11")),
    array("Dudley Currie", strtotime("2017-02-10"))
);


$tmp = 366;
$closest = ["", 0];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Bdays); $i++)
{
    if (abs($today - date($format, $Bdays[$i][1])) < $tmp)
    {
        $tmp = abs($today - date($format, $Bdays[$i][1]));
        $closest = [$Bdays[$i][0], date("Y-m-d", $Bdays[$i][1])];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks you! Appreciate your help !

Comment: @EdwardK no problem. As long as you've found a solution that works :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

DateTime offers you a diff method, which is easy to use. If a precision of days is enough, you can use the days property of that result to compare your dates. Then you have to store the index of the lowest delta and in the end you can fetch the according element in the array

```
<?php

$today = new DateTime();

$Bdays = array
(
    array("Lucienne Adkisson", date_create("2017-10-17")),
    array("Sheryll Nestle", date_create("2017-02-16")),
    array("Tim Pittman", date_create("2017-07-29")),
    array("Elmer Letts", date_create("2017-12-01")),
    array("Gino Massengale", date_create("2017-04-16")),
    array("Jeremy Wiggs ", date_create("2017-09-17")),
    array("Julian Bulloch ", date_create("2017-06 -21")),
    array("Joella Hinshaw  ", date_create("2017-06-25")),
    array("Mamie Burchill  ", date_create("2017-11-15")),
    array("Constance Segers  ", date_create("2017-06-30")),
    array("Jessy Pinkmann", date_create("2017-09-11")),
    array("Dudley Currie", date_create("2017-02-10"))
);

$len = count($Bdays);
$minDiff = PHP_INT_MAX;
$minIndex = -1;

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $diff = $today->diff($Bdays[$i][1]);

    if ($diff->days < $minDiff) {
        $minIndex = $i;
        $minDiff = $diff->days;
    }
}

print_r($Bdays[$minIndex]);
```

Comment: Thanks for useful info !

Answer (score 1):

This is a example with the "Arrayy"-class. "$currentDate" is fixed in the example, so that the result is the same every day.

Unit-Test: https://github.com/voku/Arrayy/blob/master/tests/ArrayyTest.php#L2511

Install: `composer require voku/arrayy`

Example:

```
$birthDates = array(
    array('Lucienne Adkisson', date_create('2017-10-17')),
    array('Sheryll Nestle', date_create('2017-02-16')),
    array('Tim Pittman', date_create('2017-07-29')),
    array('Elmer Letts', date_create('2017-12-01')),
    array('Gino Massengale', date_create('2017-04-16')),
    array('Jeremy Wiggs', date_create('2017-09-17')),
    array('Julian Bulloch', date_create('2017-06 -21')),
    array('Joella Hinshaw', date_create('2017-06-25')),
    array('Mamie Burchill', date_create('2017-11-15')),
    array('Constance Segers', date_create('2017-06-30')),
    array('Jessy Pinkmann', date_create('2017-09-11')),
    array('Dudley Currie', date_create('2017-02-10')),
);

$birthDatesAraayy = new Arrayy($birthDates);
$currentDate = new \DateTime('2017-09-11');
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

/**
 * sort by date - helper-function
 *
 * @param array $a
 * @param array $b
 *
 * @return int
 */
$closureSort = function ($a, $b) use ($format) {
  /* @var $aDate \DateTime */
  /* @var $bDate \DateTime */
  $aDate = $a[1];
  $bDate = $b[1];

  if ($aDate->format($format) === $bDate->format($format)) {
    return 0;
  }

  return $aDate->format($format) > $bDate->format($format) ? -1 : 1;
};

/**
 * reduce by date - helper-function
 *
 * @param array $resultArray
 * @param array $value
 *
 * @return array
 */
$closureReduce = function ($resultArray, $value) use ($currentDate) {
  /* @var $valueDate \DateTime */
  $valueDate = $value[1];

  $valueDateInterval = $currentDate->diff($valueDate);

  if ($valueDateInterval->format('%R%a') >= 0) {
    $resultArray['thisYear'][] = $value;
  } else {
    $value[1] = $valueDate->modify('+1 year');

    $resultArray['nextYear'][] = $value;
  }

  return $resultArray;
};

//
// reduce && sort the array
//

/* @var $resultMatch Arrayy|Arrayy[] */
$resultMatch = $birthDatesAraayy->reduce($closureReduce);

$thisYear = $resultMatch['thisYear']->customSortValues($closureSort);
$nextYear = $resultMatch['nextYear']->customSortValues($closureSort);

$resultMatch = $nextYear->reverse()->mergePrependNewIndex($thisYear->reverse()->getArray());

//
// check the result
//

self::assertEquals(
    array(
        array('Jessy Pinkmann', date_create('2017-09-11')),
        array('Jeremy Wiggs', date_create('2017-09-17')),
        array('Lucienne Adkisson', date_create('2017-10-17')),
        array('Mamie Burchill', date_create('2017-11-15')),
        array('Elmer Letts', date_create('2017-12-01')),
        array('Dudley Currie', date_create('2018-02-10')),
        array('Sheryll Nestle', date_create('2018-02-16')),
        array('Gino Massengale', date_create('2018-04-16')),
        array('Julian Bulloch', date_create('2018-06 -21')),
        array('Joella Hinshaw', date_create('2018-06-25')),
        array('Constance Segers', date_create('2018-06-30')),
        array('Tim Pittman', date_create('2018-07-29')),
    ),
    $resultMatch->getArray()
);
```